# Compass/Sinatra Loading Modules

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to load the CSS3 and reset modules within my SCSS files, but I'm getting an error when trying to import any Compass-specific module.

Sinatra App:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sass'
require 'compass'

configure do
  set :scss, {:style => :compact, :debug_info => false}
  Compass.add_project_configuration(File.join(Sinatra::Application.root, 'config',     'compass.rb'))
end

get '/css/:name.css' do
  content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
  scss(:"stylesheets/#{params[:name]}" )
end
```

style.scss:

```
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";
```

Error Message:

```
Sass::SyntaxError at /css/style.css
File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset. Load path: /Users/work/repos/mysite
```

Is there a gem I can install to automatically pull these modules, or do I have to move the Compass files into my Sinatra application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a correct configuration in your compass.rb, usually is enough to add something like:

```
   get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do
    content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
    sass params[:name].to_sym, Compass.sass_engine_options
   end
```

to your routes.   [Sinatra Integration](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/wiki/Sinatra-Integration), [Sample project](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-sinatra), or something you may consider useful: [Better Compass integration for Sinatra (extracted from BigBand)](https://github.com/rkh/sinatra-compass)

In a modular [Modular App](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sinatra%3a%3aBase%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) I use something like:

```
module Assets
  # #Sass/Compass Handler
  class Stylesheets < Sinatra::Base
    register  CompassInitializer
    get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do
      content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
      sass params[:name].to_sym, Compass.sass_engine_options
    end
  end
end
```

and I have in my `lib` folder a file `compass_plugin.rb`

```
module CompassInitializer
  def self.registered(app)
require 'sass/plugin/rack'
Compass.configuration do |config|
  config.project_path = Padrino.root
  config.sass_dir = "app/stylesheets"
  config.project_type = :stand_alone
  config.http_path = "/"
  config.css_dir = "public/stylesheets"
  config.images_dir = "public/images"
  config.javascripts_dir = "public/javascripts"
  config.output_style = :compressed
end
Compass.configure_sass_plugin!
Compass.handle_configuration_change!
app.use Sass::Plugin::Rack
  end
end
```

which is shamelessly  stolen from [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) framework

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just:

```
$ gem install compass
$ compass create
```